# Call cloud functions without waiting for response

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-cloud-functions, vercel

Trying a little hack here with cloud functions but can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

I'm currently using now.sh to host serverless functions and would like to call 1 function from another. Lets say I have 2 functions declared `fetchData` & `setData`. When the `setData` function is called it processes some data and then calls the `fetchData` function.

```js
export const setData = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  await axios.post(
    fetchDataEndpointUrl,
    {
      params: {
        key,
      },
    },
  );

  return res.json({
    payload: true,
  });

}
```

The above code works fine but the time taken for the entire operation to complete would be setData function call + the time taken for the fetchData function call to complete. What I'm trying to do is make a call to `fetchData` without having to wait for it to complete essentially removing the `await` in the axios call. I've tried removing the `await` but the call just ends abruptly when the `setData` call ends. Is there a way to decouple this action and not have to wait for the `setData` function to complete?

Comment: Essentially `setData` is a background task. Im not sure of the infrastructure on `now.sh` but you'll usually implement this with some `pub/sub` architecture. I've done something like this on `GCP`

Comment: does `setData` accept a `next` argument? perhaps returning a response in the first brick of the chain and then calling the axios function in a separate brick would do?
[more here](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3275-you-can-continue-to-process-an-express-js-request-after-the-client-response-has-been-sent.htm)

Comment: @shukar considering this is a serverless architecture, I don't think passing the `next`  function over the network would serve any purpose.

Comment: I've done similar things with Firebase Cloud Functions, where I would use a "trigger" HTTPS request, which saves the intended job to Cloud Firestore which triggers a [secondary Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/extend-with-functions) to do the long-running stuff. The benefit of this is that the client can also listen to updates on that Firestore document to get the results

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The summary of your question appears to be that when you call a Cloud Function, you want it to be able to return a value to its caller while simultaneously performing background work such as calling another service and waiting for a response.

When you return a value to the caller for a Cloud Function, that is the end of the life span of the Cloud Function.  You can not be assured of any kind of *life* in the Cloud Function beyond the return.

This is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#function_execution_timeline).

The text (in part) reads:

> A function has access to the resources requested (CPU and memory) only
>   for the duration of function execution. Code run outside of the
>   execution period is not guaranteed to execute, and it can be stopped
>   at any time. Therefore, you should always signal the end of your
>   function execution correctly and avoid running any code beyond it.

Another part of the question is what if we want to have our Cloud Function make an asynchronous REST call where we don't care about waiting for the response.  Can we return from the Cloud Function without waiting for the nested REST call to complete?

The answer is *maybe* but it will depend on the nature of service being called and how we are calling it.  To appreciate the nuances in this remember that JavaScript is a single threaded language.  There aren't multiple threads of execution.  In our JavaScript app, only one thing will ever happen at a time.  If we make an asynchronous REST call and don't care about a reply but (obviously) do care that the request has been sent then we need to synchronously send the request before we terminate the Cloud Function.  This can get tricky if we start using library packages without delving into their natures.  For example, a REST call might include:

- A socket connection to the partner
- A transmission of the outbound request
- A callback when the response is received

We need to be absolutely sure that the transmission has happened before we end the top level Cloud Function call.  In addition, if we do end the top level Cloud Function call, that may very well tare down the socket used for the response.  This could result in an exception in the called REST service that now is unable to return its 200 response.

To run work where we don't need to nor want to wait for a response, GCP provides an architected solution for this.  It is called "Cloud Tasks" (see [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/)).  Within your Cloud Function, you would define a request to call your nested service asynchronously and hand that request off to Cloud Tasks to execute.  Cloud Tasks would acknowledge receipt of the request to execute and you can now be assured that it will and can return at the highest level.

Comment: went throught the doc, I actually do not need to wait for the response from the background task, I just need it to fire and execute on its own. Considering these are independent cloud functions, doesn't invoking one from another count as a separate cloud function invocation, why is it considered as a background task?

Comment: I've attempted to add some more words into the answer.  We might also want to look at Cloud Tasks as a component in the answer.

Comment: @Kolban
I believe we still need to wait for Cloud Tasks to acknowledge receipt.

Hence, the workaround makes sense if the service we are calling has a higher ping time than the "CloudTask Acknowledge" request, right?

Do you think this is viable for calling "third-party email service" from a GCP function?

Comment: @Mehari ... I think we would call Cloud Tasks to schedule a task to be executed and wait for the call to Cloud Tasks to complete before completing the Cloud Function call.